# Separating unique values within the same dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have  a huge dataset. What I am trying to do is separate unique names and calculate the genetic algorithm of data with the same name. to illustrate

Assume the following table

```
Name    price     quantity     
a1.     100.       6
a2.     30.        20
a1      250.       125
a1.     5.         20
a2.     90.        200
a2.     50.        705
```

so I want to calculate the genetic algorithm of a1 and a2 separately to get the best solution for x1-x3. I have already coded the genetic algorithm for the whole dataset, but I am confused about how to calculate a1 and a2 separately within the same dataset.

Note: I have used pandas to import my dataset

Comment: If you want to calculate only the rows named 'a1.' or 'a2.' you may slice the dataset that way, assuming your DataFrame is `df`: `df.loc[df.Name == 'a1.']` and `df.loc[df.Name == 'a2.']`. Tell me if this isn't what you meant and I'll try to help further.

Comment: @n.shabankin this is exactly what I meant.. but in reality its not a1 and a2..
I have a very huge dataset with 200 rows and 30 different combinations.. is there is a way that i can extract unique values without explicitly writing them like you did?

Comment: Did you check the [`.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) method?

Comment: @n.shabankin well yes.. but i still can't figure out how to do it with 30 different unique names.. and no i don't want to form pairs.. all what i want to do is to separate a1 till a30 from each other and calculate the genetic algorithm. a1 for example will have 4 rows then i am calculating the GA, then i want to move to a2 which has 20 rows then do the same calculations, and then to a3 till a30

Comment: @n.shabankin sorry i've just edited my comment. sorry for the inconvenience, can you check it out

Comment: `for i in df.Name.unique():` and then you do what you want with `df.loc[df.names==i]` as @n.shabankin suggested in it's first comment.

Comment: @it'sM sorry again I just read that you didn't want the pairs but to calculate over unique names. There's an answer for that in Ignatius Reilly's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*With regards to @IgnatiusReilly for adding to the question in the comments.*

If you want to slice your DataFrame into chunks for every unique name to perform calculations over them, you may do the following:

```py
# assume there's a function ga() that calculates the genetic algorithm for a column 
# and your DataFrame is df
for name in df.Name.unique():
    ga(df.loc[df.Name == name])
```

As for applying this to calculate `geneticalgorithm`, I have a humble assumption this might look like this:

```py
from geneticalgorithm import geneticalgorithm as ga

for name in df.Name.unique():
    s = df.loc[df.Name == name].to_numpy()  # convert to ndarray
    # take columns from 1 to 3 if 'Name' is indexed 0
    varbound = np.array([[np.min(s[:, 1]), np.max(s[:, 1])],
                         [np.min(s[:, 2]), np.max(s[:, 2])],
                         [np.min(s[:, 3]), np.max(s[:, 3])]])
    model = ga(function=equ,  # this function has been declared somewhere before
               dimension=3,
               variable_type='int',
               variable_boundaries=varbound)
    model.run()
```

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly thanks! Now it's correct. Btw, do you know if there's a common practice to point out other user's contribution to an answer that another user had compiled after discussion in the comments? Though it's no big deal in this particular case, I still felt like I had to mention your share here.

Comment: I've seen that's a lot and I do it myself. So, if you feel my comment helped you, it's fine! Thanks!

Comment: @n.shabankin hello again! I want to understand why ga in your code has a single parameter. I've already defined my GA with geneticAlgorithms package and its as follows: model=ga(function=equ,dimension=3,variable_type='int',variable_boundaries=varbound)

do you have any idea on how to fit your code in this kind of parameters?

Comment: @it'sM well, I only assumed there is some kind of a function I called `ga()` just to illustrate how you can pass those slices a DataFrame into it. Looks like in that particular case those slices need some operations performed with them. What did you do with the `function` and `variable_boundaries` parameters when calculated on your whole dataset?

Comment: @n.shabankin for function parameter I just called and equation function that will calculate equation and find coefficient and then I sat my constraints within an array

Comment: @it'sM I tried to read the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/geneticalgorithm/) for `geneticalgorithm` to figure out what you must do with your data. I can't say I truly understand the idea but you might need to pass min and max values of each of two columns as constraints in the `varbound` variable within a loop and then pass it into the function. However, your function has `dimension=3` but there seems to be only 2 variables, or am I wrong?

Comment: @n.shabankin in my actual dataset its 3 variables..

Comment: @it'sM I tried to guess how your working around `ga()` function might look like though I don't know much about this function, but please check out the edits to the answer.